# How can I click on a button using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I click on a Button with my Python code? I write a programm, which should log me in on an website. Now i have to click on a button and it dosen't work. I tried every method I found on the Internet. It still wont work and I donk know why.

Currently I use Selenium 4.9.0

```
import time from selenium
import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by  
import By from selenium.webdriver.common.keys   
import Keys from selenium.webdriver.support.ui 
import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support    
import expected_conditions as EC
```

this is the Button from the HTML-Site:

```
<form class="un-form form-inline"><div><button type="button" title="Abwesenheit melden" class="btn btn-primary">Abwesenheit melden</button><button type="button" title="Löschen" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</button><div class="dropup btn-group"><button id="8a4bb522-063d-4eca-a121-3f32933a3a1e" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">Entschuldigungsschreiben drucken <span class="caret"></span></button><ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="8a4bb522-063d-4eca-a121-3f32933a3a1e"><li role="presentation" class=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">pro Stunde</a></li><li role="presentation" class=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">pro Tag</a></li></ul></div></div></form>
```

This the ID which I got from the web addon from selenium:

`"id": "f2a5983c-bdd9-4373-804b-af70cd7ad751",`

`"comment": "",`

`"command": "click",`

`"target": "css=.btn-primary",`

`"targets": [         ["css=.btn-primary", "css:finder"],`

`["xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[46]", "xpath:attributes"],         ["xpath=//div[@id='dijit_layout__LayoutWidget_0']/section/div/section/div/div/div[3]/form/div          /button", "xpath:idRelative"],`

`["xpath=//form/div/button", "xpath:position"],`

`["xpath=//button[contains(.,'Abwesenheit melden')]", "xpath:innerText"]       ],`

`"value": ""`

I just want to do an click on a singel button. I didn't understand why I cant click on a Button, I know that some attempts are for an older version but the older version didn't work neither.
those were my attempts:

```
 
element = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="f2a5983c-bdd9-4373-804b-af70cd7ad751"]')


element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dijit_layout__LayoutWidget_0']/section/div/section/div/div/div[3]/form/div/button")
element.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@title="Abwesenheit melden" and @class="btn btn-primary"]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/div[3]/form/div/button[1]'))).click()


button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dijit_layout__LayoutWidget_0']/section/div/section/div/div/div[3]/form/div/button")
#button.click()
```

Comment: Please read this once [What makes a good selenium locator?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clean up the "Button from the HTML-Site" code. It doesn't make any sense. Can you include the HTML as plain text?

Answer (score 1):

The button-element you mentioned does not have an id, thus you cannot use an id with the xpath-selector. If you have only one button on the website, you could try the CSS selector:

`element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')`

If you have more buttons on the page and the button you want to click is e.g. button number 2 try

`element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')[1]`

**Edit:**

Based on your updated HTML snippet I created the following minimal Website:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="un-form form-inline">
            <div>
                <button type="button" title="Abwesenheit melden" class="btn btn-primary">Abwesenheit melden</button>
                <button type="button" title="Löschen" class="btn btn-danger">Löschen</button>
                <div class="dropup btn-group">
                    <button id="8a4bb522-063d-4eca-a121-3f32933a3a1e" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">Entschuldigungsschreiben drucken <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="8a4bb522-063d-4eca-a121-3f32933a3a1e">
                        <li role="presentation" class=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">pro Stunde</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class=""><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">pro Tag</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the following Python script, I was able to click the button "Abwesenheit melden":

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                          executable_path="Driver/chromedriver")
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/stefan/Desktop/selenium_test.html")

element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't work either. This was the error msg:     element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn-primary')[1]           
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are there two or more buttons on the website, having the same CSS-class "btn-primary"? The `[1]` should select the second button-element with that class.

Comment: There is only one but I tried the fist one too

Comment: Could you post the html source of the page, as @Greg Burghardt asked. Otherwise this turnes out to be a quiz, I think.

Comment: I updated the HTML code but I can't post more of it

Comment: I created a test website - see edit - and it worked for me. So in your case there seems to be another problem than the selector.

Comment: somethimes this error happend. I also dont konw how and why? my Usb port is fine. I can use it and when i run an software/hardware check there isn't an error. Its only when I start this programm. :[6736:10740:0530/103837.310:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [10:38:37.306] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (0x2)